# how to get request url?

Tags: craft3, url, request

I'm trying to get url from request,

```
 {{ craft.app.request.url }}
```

but the uri is chinese, like "localhost/測試",

it print out "http://localhost/����"

did i miss some setting in craft CMS ?

Thank you.

Comment: http://localhost//����

Comment: Guessing you need to set `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your template?

Comment: @BradBell Thanks your help! I trid, but not working.

Comment: Maybe a server-side thing? If you go to Utilities->PHP Info in the Craft control panel and search for `default_charset`, what is it set to?

Comment: The setting is "UTF-8".  
I try Request class methods, the getAbsoluteUrl() has same problem, "http://localhost/����".  But getFullPath(), getFullUri() and getSegment(1) can show chinese, "測試" .
Sorry I am new in Craft CMS and programing.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but my investigating was too long for a comment.

Ultimately, `craft.app.request.url` gets routed through Yii's [resolveRequestUri()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Request.php#L1052) and likely gets pulled from [$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Request.php#L1057).

Anything coming from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is always going to be URL encoded so using this in a template:

[image]

I get this URL encoded output in a browser:

[image]

Unfortunately, Twig doesn't have a `|url_decode` [filter](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/issues/60), so you'd need to write a quick custom Twig filter that uses PHP's [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) method.

But it actually looks like you're having a character encoding issue first because of the `����` and I'm not exactly sure what's causing that.

My guess is its environment configuration related (I'm using https://getnitro.sh in a fairly default setup for testing).